# cannot retrieve correct data from table

Tags: java, mysql, database, eclipse, business-logic

Below is the assignment target for each person assigned for each day. Person A to be assigned on 1 Nov t hit 200 targets, Person B to be assigned on 2 Nov to hit 200 targets, Person C to be assigned on 3 Nov to hit 200 targets

Y

```
Date   | Person | Target
1-Nov  |  A     | 200 -allocated date, person and target
2 Nov  |  B     | 200 -allocated date, person and target
3-Nov  |  C     | 200 -allocated date, person and target
4-Nov  |  D     | 200 -allocated date, person and target
```

But the issue comes here, on 1 Nov,if Person A hits target of 200, he has finished his target for the day and Person B will take over the next 200.When Person B hit target of 200, Person C will take over the next 200 this time. If Person C has not hit target of 200. He will continue the next day(2 Nov). On 3 Nov, it will automatically assign to Person D even when Person C has not reach the 200 target, reason is because it is the next day. So Person C can rest and Person D will take over the first 200 target. So record ends up as

Z

```
Date   | Person | Target
1-Nov  |  A     | 200
1-Nov  |  B     | 200
1-Nov  |  C     | 150
2 Nov  |  C     | 20
3-Nov  |  D     | 100
```

Is there any way to create a table and column to cater for this scenario? Or else retrieve data from the table?? As this is required.

1. Tried using IDs (eg. 1, 2, 3) but there might be issues in retrieving data.
2. Tried retrieving max(date) by it would have referred to the wrong date
   E.g the date is 2 nov 
   looking from Y..Person B is suppose to hit target of 200. But looking from Z, B had already done on 1 nov, C also did on 1 nov but it did not hit target of 200. So on 2 nov Person C will continue. Z and Y is the same table. So if you search by max it would have read 4-nov Person D 200 which is the wrong data
3. Z and Y is the same table..
4. if on 1 nov, data will be displayed as

H

```
Date   | Person | Target
1-Nov  |  A     | 200 - On Nov 1, have 550 data and will be assign to A, B and C referring to 'allocated date, person and target'
1-Nov  |  B     | 200
1-Nov  |  C     | 150
2 Nov  |  B     | 200 - allocated date, person and target
3-Nov  |  C     | 200 - allocated date, person and target
4-Nov  |  D     | 200 - allocated date, person and target
```

allocated date, person and target does not mean he has done target of 200. It is 0 and only allocated value..the purpose is to check who is the next person on the list to continue the target
What I need is to check on Y if there is any person allocated and if he/she has hit target of 200. If yes, it will look for the next person in queue to continue the next 200. 
Problem is how to retrieve data to check if the person has hit target 200 or have they passed their allocated date..?

Comment: What can possibly go wrong if you request data by id? And tis unclear what are you trying to achieve with #2, but you can get sum of all hits made by Person with [`SUM`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_sum.asp) operator like this: `SELECT Person, SUM(Target) AS Total FROM Z GROUP BY Person`

Comment: if i create a column for id..it would not go wrong but it doesn't retrieve the data which i need. #2 On 2 nov, from table Y, Person B is suppose to start target but on table Z, Person B did target already on 1 nov. So Person C will start target from 150 onwards. Note table Y and Z is the same table. So MAX(date) would not work..

Comment: I think a better idea would be to establish fairer, legally compliant working practices